# Помогите разобраться с указателями C

Tags: c, указатели

Сейчас изучаю указатели и пытаюсь выполнить по ним задачу,но на данный момент очень сильно в них запутался(особенно с функцией,которая возвращает указатель на тип Т1). Посмотрите,пожалуйста код,и скажите где я допустил ошибки,и как можно их исправить.

Код должен выполнять это задание:
Присвоить разименованному указателю на тип Т1(long)(я так понимаю подразумевается long double) значение арифметического выражения А( sin(p1)/tan(p2) ),которое включает в себя переменные p1,p2,связанные с указателями на типы Т2(int),T3(float). Арифметическое выражение реализовать в виде функции которая возвращает указатель на тип Т1. Вывести на экран значение указателя на тип Т2 и значение переменной,на которую он посылается.
Код работает,но значение Т1 выводит 0

```
    #include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

long * A(long * r ,int * p1,float * p2)
 {
  *r = sin(*p1)/tan(*p2);
  return r ; }
int main()
 {

   int *p1;
  float *p2;
 int a;
 float b;

 //  long *T1;
//   *T1=*r; 
  printf("Enter a\n");
  scanf("%i",&a);
  p1=&a;
  printf("Enter b\n");
  scanf("%f",&b);
  p2=&b;

  printf("adress T2=%x",p1);// Âûâåë çíà÷åíèå óêàçàòåëÿ íà òèï int(àäðåñ ïåðåìåííîé íà êîòîðóþ îí ññûëàåòñÿ)
  printf("\nvalue T2=%d",*p1);// Âûâåë çíà÷åíèå ïåðåìåííîé íà êîòîðóþ ññûëêàåòñÿ óêàçàòåëü íà òèï int
long r;
 A(& r , p1, p2); 

printf("\n||Adress T1=%p||",(void*)&r);
 printf("\n||Value T1=%li||",r);    


}
```

Comment: удалите `#include<iostream>` и `using namespace std;`. Такого в языке нет.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Удалил и отредактировал код,правда  я еще не разобрался с тем,как вывести r.

Comment: `long r;
  A(& r , p1, p2);
    printf("\n||Adress T1=%p||",(void*)&r);
    printf("\n||Value T1=%li||",r);`

Comment: @AlexGlebe Добавил эти строчки,но значение r выводит 0.

Comment: Подбирайте правильные числа, результат обрубается до целого.

Comment: Вы сами сказали: "я так понимаю подразумевается long double". Но в коде у вас просто `long`, который `long int`. Так что же именно подразумевается?`long double` или `long int`?

Comment: @AnT Это уже исправленный и рабочий код,в начале был long double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С задачей всё напутано, я понимаю так: принимаем указатели `p1` и `p2`. И в разыменованный указатель `r` присваиваем значение. Может я не так понял, не знаю.

```
long * A(long * r ,int * p1,float * p2) {
  *r = sin(*p1)/tan(*p2);
  return r ; }
```

В языке тип  `long` по умолчанию подразумевается целый тип `long int`. Ваша ошибка: вы возвращаете указатель на локальную переменную, который после завершения работы функции больше не ликвидно. Значение этой переменной хранится в стеке (как бы временное хранилище данных, общее для любых функций процесса).

Comment: Я сейчас попытаюсь исправить код,сможете оценить его позже?