# Как вывести в ответ адрес функции?

Tags: c, функции, указатели

Как можно вывести адрес функции в ответ в этом коде? Необходимо использовать printf и в коде при выводе нельзя использовать 'A(p1,p2)' . Перепробовал уже все,но не выходит… Если сделать так -printf("%x",A(p1,p2);,то адрес выводится, но если делаю как нужно- printf("%x",A),то выводится 401500.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
long * A(int * p1,float * p2)
 {long * r ;
  *r = sin(*p1)/tan(*p2);
  return r ; }
int main()
 {

   int *p1;
  float *p2;
 int a;
 float b;


  printf("Enter a\n");
  scanf("%i",&a);
  p1=&a;
  printf("Enter b\n");
  scanf("%f",&b);
  p2=&b;

  printf("value of pointer on type T2=%x",p1);
  printf("\nvalue of variable T2=%d",*p1);
long r;
 A( p1, p2); 

printf("\nAdress of answer=%x",(void*)&r);
 printf("\nAnswer=%li",r);  
 printf("Adress of function=%x",*A);


}
```

Comment: Не пробовали выводить, как положено для адреса - с `%p`? А воробще, что за ерунду вы делаете - `long * r ;
  *r = sin(*p1)/tan(*p2);` - **куда**, по-вашему, будет записано вычисленное значение? Что вы выводите в `printf("\nAnswer=%li",r);`, если `r` у вас не инициализированная переменная? Короче, весь код - один большой вопрос, чтоб не выразиться жестче...

Comment: @Harry Попробовал через %p- выводит 00400500. В моем понимании будет записано в *r. r выводится нормально кстати.

Comment: 1. А что вам нужно? Выводится адрес функции. 2. А **куда** указывает *локальная неинициализированная* переменная `r`? В ней же какое-то "левое" значение... 3. И вы проверяли - это именно то значение, которое вы посчитали? :) Проверьте...

Comment: Проверял,выводится действительно нужный мне ответ(правда округленный) . Нужно что бы адрес выводился таком же виде как и при его выводе 'printf("%x",A(p1,p2);' или как при выводе 'p1', Просто то,что получается сейчас на адрес совсем не похоже.Или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: А как, по-вашему, выглядит адрес? И еще - ну поподставляйте вы разные значения при вводе, и посмотрите... Неужели вы не видите, что результат вычислений вы просто теряете? не говорю уж, что портите при этом память...

Comment: @Harry
Ну к примеру как-то так
p1= 006afe94
p2=006afe90
r=006afe8c
функция=00401500
Почему такая сильная разница?

Comment: А разницу между кодом и стеком вы не видите?

Comment: Вижу,но ведь если я использую  'printf("%x",A(p1,p2);' ,то адрес всегда выводится в таком же виде,например  006afe2c . И я действительно не могу понять почему такая разница,тем более что от меня требуют что бы ответ выводился именно в таком виде - 006afe2c, при использовании printf("Adress of function=%x",*A);,ну а следовательно как-то да можно вывести адрес в виде 006afe2c?

Comment: Вот тут - `printf("%x",A(p1,p2));` - вы выводите какое-то левое значение, хранящееся в локальной переменной функции `A` и возвращаемое из нее... Дальше - как хотите, но я выхожу из диалога типа "- 2*2 = 4. - Да, но 3*3 = 9, и я хочу, чтоб 2*2 было рядом, скажем, 8"...

Comment: Это не вы ли были? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/934403/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Язык С в общем случае не предоставляет готового способа "вывести адрес функции". Предоставляемые языком средства вывода предназначены только для работы с указателями на данные, но не с указателями на функции.

Надежда в вашем случае фактически только на то, что ваша реализация позволяет вам "насильно" преобразовывать указатели на функции к типу `void *` (с сохранением "осмысленности" результата). В таком случае вы сможете воспользоваться форматом `%p` в `printf`

```
printf("Address of function = %p\n", (void *) A);
```

Формат `%x` предназначен для вывода целых чисел и не может применяться для вывода "адресов", поэтому не ясно, что вы имеете в виду под вывом "как через `%x`". Ваш

```
printf("value of pointer on type T2=%x",p1);
```

совершенно некорректен. Правильно

```
printf("value of pointer on type T2=%p\n", (void *) p1);
```

Обратите внимание на обязательное приведение к типу `void *`.

Если вам по какой-то причине все таки нужны какие-то особенности вывода, предоставляемые форматом `%x`, то применить его для вывода "адресов" можно так

```
#include <inttypes.h>
... 
printf("value of pointer on type T2=%" PRIxPTR "\n",
  (uintptr_t) p1);
```

P.S. Это не говоря уже об огромном количестве не связанных с этим вопросом ошибок и несуразностей в приведенном коде.

Answer (score 2):

Вот немного комментариев к вашей программе (увы, как комментарий поместить не могу):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

long * A(int * p1, float * p2)
{
    long * r ;
    *r = sin(*p1)/tan(*p2);      // Запись в некоторое неизвестное место в памяти
    return r ;                   // Возврат этого "левого" адреса
}

int main()
{

    int *p1;
    float *p2;
    int a;
    float b;


    printf("Enter a\n");
    scanf("%i",&a);
    p1=&a;

    printf("Enter b\n");
    scanf("%f",&b);
    p2=&b;

    printf("value of pointer on type T2=%p\n\n",p1);  // Адреса выводите как %p
    printf("value of variable T2=%d\n\n",*p1);

    long r;                                       // неизвестное значение
    A( p1, p2);                                   // Результат: что-то записано куда-то и потеряно
                                                  // С большой вероятностью приведет к падению программы

    printf("Adress of answer=%p\n\n",&r);         // Адрес локальной переменной `r`
    printf("Answer=%li\n\n",r);                   // значение в ней (неизвестное)
    printf("Adress of function=%p\n\n",A);        // Адрес функции, все верно


}
```